# Why my service sending 20 requests per second instead of 1 per 10 sec

Tags: java, android, http

I am trying to make service that sending requests every 10 seconds.
The main task is to make request every 10 seconds and update the list of objects in recycleview.

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Binder;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

public class HttpSenderService extends Service {
private String SERVER_IP;
private int PORT;
HttpSenderServiceBinder binder = new HttpSenderServiceBinder();

Runnable mHandlerTask = new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run() {
        new makeRequest().execute();
        mHandler.postDelayed(mHandlerTask, 3000);
    }
};

public HttpSenderService() {
}

private static String TAG = HttpSenderService.class.getSimpleName();
private String msgGetWarningAlarm = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><request><track_get_warning_alarm version=\"" + MainActivity.reqV + "\"/></request>";
public boolean isRunning = false;
private String response_str;
Handler mHandler;

String getResponse_str(){
    return response_str;
}


@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return binder;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");
    mHandler = new Handler();
    SharedPreferences mySettings = getSharedPreferences("MainActivity", MODE_PRIVATE);
    if (!mySettings.getString("SERVER_IP", "").equals("")) {
        SERVER_IP = mySettings.getString("SERVER_IP", "");
    }
    PORT = mySettings.getInt("PORT", 0);
}

@Override
public synchronized void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");
    stopRepeatingTask();
}

@Override
public synchronized void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    super.onStart(intent, startId);
    Log.d(TAG, "onStart");
    startRepeatingTask();
}

//...........
private class makeRequest extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... v) {
        try {
            if (SERVER_IP != null && !SERVER_IP.equals("") && PORT > 0) {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://" + SERVER_IP + ":" + Integer.toString(PORT) + "/");
                // Add your data
                StringEntity se = null;
                try {
                    se = new StringEntity(msgGetWarningAlarm);
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                se.setContentType("text/xml");
                httppost.setEntity(se);
                ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
                response_str = null;
                try {
                    response_str = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);
                    if (!response_str.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                        return null;
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void v) {
        fireReturnListeners(HttpSenderService.this);
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new makeRequest().execute();
            }
        }, 10000);
    }
}

public interface HttpReceivedListener {
    void onHttpReceived(HttpSenderService service);
    // or void onEvent(); as per your need
}

private ArrayList<HttpSenderService.HttpReceivedListener> listeners = new ArrayList<HttpSenderService.HttpReceivedListener>();

public void addHttpReceivedListener(HttpSenderService.HttpReceivedListener listener) {
    listeners.add(listener);
}

public void removeReturnListener(HttpSenderService.HttpReceivedListener listener) {
    listeners.remove(listener);
}

private void fireReturnListeners(HttpSenderService service) {
    for (HttpSenderService.HttpReceivedListener listener : listeners) {
        listener.onHttpReceived(service);
    }
}

class HttpSenderServiceBinder extends Binder {
    HttpSenderService getService() {
        return HttpSenderService.this;
    }
}

void startRepeatingTask()
{
    mHandlerTask.run();
}

void stopRepeatingTask()
{
    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mHandlerTask);
}
}
```

Please tell how to make right the service like this. The previous version of the app was without service and requests was implemented with alarm manager, the next version was with the service with Thread, and now I am trying to do that with async task but when I start the service it makes to match requests. Maybe there is some library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are posting messages to handler from (at least) two places AsyncTaks.postExecute and mHandlerTask its self. so, when it's placed first time it triggers next two executions of its self then 4, 8, 16... as long and as fast as hardware is able to process those demands.

```
Runnable mHandlerTask = new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run() {
        new makeRequest().execute();
        mHandler.postDelayed(mHandlerTask, 3000); //remove this line!
    }
};
```

/or this block

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        new makeRequest().execute();
    }
}, 10000);
```

Comment: Thank`s!
My inattention will kill somebody someday

Answer (score 0):

Move the timing code:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void v) {
    fireReturnListeners(HttpSenderService.this);
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new makeRequest().execute();
        }
    }, 10000);
}
```

Change this:

```
void startRepeatingTask()
{
    mHandlerTask.run();
}
```

to this:

```
void startRepeatingTask()
{
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new makeRequest().execute();
        }
    }, 10000);

}
```

You are creating a new Handler.postDelayed every time the code runs which is why you eventually send 20 requests. Remove the repeating in onPostExecute.

What you did "wrong" is recursive calls. These recreate themselves and because of the placement you create more handlers every time the code is called.